# power bank charging while being charged

Tags: raspberry-pi, power-bank, ups

I'm using **Tecknet** 16750mAh power banks to provide power to Raspberry Pis. I'm really happy with them. Power is provided uninterrupted when the bank is being charged, when the bank charging power goes down and when it comes back. **Not all banks do that**: I have tested some other banks where there was a  interruption when the power charging the bank  was coming back. And there are banks that just disconnect their load. Each USB is able to deliver 2,4A (3.4A max on both) so the RPi runs smoothly and is protected against grid outages, even the long ones (several hours). One of my RPis has 2y+ uptime.

Unfortunately, since some months all Tecknet banks are out of stock.

I'm looking for alternatives with the following requirements

- Capacity >12000mAh
- One USB port is OK
- Charging power provided when the bank is being charged, when the bank charging power is down and when it comes back.

Thanks in advance